# Normals are Rendered Black

Tags: python, normal-map

I am trying to render a normal map of an object from various angles and certain orientations are rendering black:

[image]

[image]

Where as the renderings from other orientations are just fine:

[image]

I suspect that the normals with negative value are being set to zero as it is seems only the negative facing faces which are rendered black I think. If this is true is there a way to fix this in code?

I have already checked and the faces seem to have outward facing normals:

[image]

Here is the code I am using to render the normals:

```
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
links = tree.links
bpy.context.view_layer.use_pass_normal = True
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_depth = '16'
render_layers = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')

normal_file_output = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeOutputFile")
normal_file_output.label = 'Normal Output'
links.new(render_layers.outputs['Normal'], normal_file_output.inputs[0])
normal_file_output.base_path = save_location + '_normal'
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].view_settings.view_transform = 'Raw'
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].view_settings.look = 'None'

bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True, write_still=True)
```

Any help would be very appreciated ! Thank you !

Comment: It's true that negative values are represented as black, and probably clamped to 0 when output as an image.

Comment: It looks like you're outputting "true normals" or normals in object space.  Would it be better for you to output normals in tangent space?

Comment: yes that would be perfect! Do you know how to do that in python?